# MySQL query not showing errors but doesn't insert

Tags: php, mysql

Problem is: Always getting error user already exists, and no insertion into database have been made. My goal here, is to register user wihout leaving homepage and do the database insertion with ajax request. Also I want the user to stay offline.

Database structure (ID autoident, username unique, email unique, password, status enum(active,inactive))

My code:
register.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php'; 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);    
        $password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password'])); 
        $result="INSERT INTO users VALUES '', '$username', '$email', '$password', 'inactive'";
        $res=mysqli_query($con, $result);
        if(mysqli_error($con, $result))
           echo mysqli_error($con, $result);
        else
           echo "Inserted Successfully";
    }
    ?>
```

config.php is for database connection

scripts.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#register').click(function() {
        var help = true;
        var username=$("#user2").val();
        var password=$("#pass21").val();
        var password2=$("#pass22").val();
        if (password != password2) {
            $("#error2").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Password mismatch! ");
            help = false;
        }
        var email=$("#email").val();
        if( !validateEmail(email)) {
            $("#error2").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Email not correct!");
            help = false;
        }
        var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password+'&email'+email;
        if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0 && help==true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "core/register.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){ $("#register").val('Connecting...');},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data="Inserted Successfully") {
                        $("#register").val('Register')
                        $("#error2").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Success");
                    } else {
                        $("#register").val('Register')
                        $("#error2").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Username or email already exists");
                    }
                }   
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});

function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test( $email );
}
```

index.php

```
<div class="formstyle-r register">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <h4>Username:</h4>
            <input type="text" name="user2" id="user2">
            <h4>Password:</h4>
            <input type="password" name="pass21" id="pass21">
            <h4>Confirm password:</h4>
            <input type="password" name="pass22" id="pass22">
            <h4>E-mail:</h4>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="custombtn1" value="Register">
            <div class="err" id="error2"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This code always gives error already exists. And never inserts into database. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the braces in your query...

```
 $result="INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$username', '$email', '$password', 'inactive')";
```

Do this and it'll work fine... Refer this link for more details about inserting values into DB..
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: No success, no errors, no new row in database, maybe is problem with ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is set as `AUTO INCREMENT`, you don't need to specify it in the `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, status) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', 'inactive');
```

Also, to improve searching by active/inactive users, you can consider changing the active column to `TINYINT(1)` and use `0` or `1` instead of text 'active'/'inactive'

Comment: didn't help in my case tho. I have username and email set as unique in table and status is inactive as deafult, if that helps. Using enum with status.

Comment: if you are trying to insert those two values twice, the query will fail, of course. You can try the `INSERT IGNORE` statement, which will not break if runs into a duplicate values, and then check the affected rows to see if anything got inserted - otherwise display an error on the client...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$result="INSERT INTO users VALUES '', '$username', '$email', '$password', 'inactive'";
```

to

```
$result="INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, status) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password."', 'inactive')";
```